# What does 'pass result to parameter' mean in this case?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm trying to solve this but the 'pass result to cb' is getting me a bit confused. If I assign the result to cb, wouldn't it ignore any arguments I may put in cb's place when I invoke the function? Any help is appreciated.

```
function sumArray(numbers, cb) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return sum; 
      // sum up all of the integers in the numbers array
      // pass the result to cb (This is my problem).
      // no return is necessary
    }
```

Comment: What's you actual question here? You can pass the sum to `cb` by `cb(sum)`.

Comment: What does pass the result of the sum mean in this problem? And I meant that if I do it the way you did it now, wouldn't it override any number or data I may use to invoke the function. Like sumArray([1, 2, 3], 5) (If I assign sum to cb, would it not conflict with the 5?) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can pass functions as parameters. In this case `cb` is probably a function where you can an argument to it. Eg

```
cb(sum)
```

cb is a common abbreviation for "call back"

The function `sumArray` could be called like this:

```
sumArray([1,2,3], function (arg1) { alert("result " + arg1) })
```

Full example:

```js
function sumArray(numbers, cb) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
      }
      cb(sum); 
      // sum up all of the integers in the numbers array
      // pass the result to cb (This is my problem).
      // no return is necessary
    }


sumArray([1,2,3], function (arg1) { alert("result " + arg1) })
```

Some further reading: [Understanding JavaScript Callbacks](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-01-17/understanding-javascript-callbacks)

Answer (score 1):

In this code `cb` stands for `callback` which is a `function` that's passed as parameter in your first function call.

Because in Javascript functions can be passed as params to other functions which is referred to as [`callback` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

So in this case "pass the result to cb", means that you will need to pass the `sum` variable to the `cb` function, so just write:

```
cb(sum);
```

For further details chack [MDN **callback function** Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

**Note:**

Make sure when you use this code, to pass a function as second parameter otherwise it will throw an error if `cb` is not a `function`.